# iOS, decrease icon badge number

Tags: ios, icons, badge

I use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber -1];
```

to decrement the icon badge count, but actually it gets cleared. when I press the home button, the badge count is not there.

BUT, if I try a fixed value like this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:4];
```

, the badge count is there as expected.

So, the question is: Why is

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber -1];
```

not working?

Comment: This piece of code works as expected for me (XCode 4.6, iOS 6.1 Simulator, put inside a view controller's `viewDidLoad` method). So I suspect there might be some other things causing this problem. Could you provide more information, like where did you place this line of code, and what's the value of `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber` there?

Comment: @RoxDorentus The code is Placed in the AppDelegate inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Answer (score 4):

Why you don't just:

```
NSInteger numberOfBadges = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber
numberOfBadges -=1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:numberOfBadges];
```

Answer (score 0):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber -1];` is your mistake

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber -1
```

is no valid operation to do there.

Use a temporary var to change the badge count, if you get confused otherwise.

Edit:
Use it like this.

```
int value = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber;
value--;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:value];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in swift for decrease

```
    let currentCountStr = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber.description
    let currentCount = Int(currentCountStr)
    if(currentCount > 0) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = currentCount! - 1
    } else {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason this doesn't work:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber -1];
```

is that it's not decrementing the badge number, it's setting it to -1.  The docs say that setting the badge number to 0 hides it, but negative numbers do also.

To decrement the badge number, at least until it reaches 0 do this:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber--;
```

applicationIconBadgeNumber can be used as a normal variable, e.g.:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 100;
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber++;
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber += 2;
```

Just make sure it stays positive if you want it to be visible.

Answer (score -2):

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[dict[@"badge"] integerValue]]+=[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber;

Comment: (- = ) should be there